# In Scala, how can I check if a generic HashMap contains a particular key?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do something like the following

```
  def defined(hash: HashMap[T, U], key: [T) {
    hash.contains(key)
  }
```

The above does not compile because my syntax is incorrect. Is it possible to check if a HashMap of unknown type contains a given key?

Comment: As of today you're the 8th all time top askers on http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/topusers. May be you can answer your own question? It's a true piece of advice, I found I've learned more by answering question on SO. Unless you're in the running to be the top asker...

Comment: So you are saying that your strategy optimises knowledge accumulation per unit of time expended?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other than the stray "[" I don't think you have a syntax error.  That and you need an "=" before your braces, or the function won't be returning the bool.  And since there is only one expression, no need for braces...

```
import scala.collection.mutable._

object Main extends App {

  def defined[T,U](hash: HashMap[T, U], key: T) = hash.contains(key)

  val m = new HashMap[String,Int]
  m.put("one", 1)
  m.put("two", 2)
  println(defined(m, "one"))
  println(m contains "two")
  println(defined(m, "three"))
}
```

Comment: oh yeah, and I added the type parameters to the method.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to define your own; because all `Map`s, and all `HashMap`s in particular, are `PartialFunction`s, you can use the `isDefinedAt` method:

```
scala> val map = HashMap(1->(), 2->())
map: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Unit] = Map(1 -> (), 2 -> ())

scala> map.isDefinedAt(2)
res9: Boolean = true

scala> map.isDefinedAt(3)
res10: Boolean = false
```

Also there is the `contains` method which is particular to `MapLike` objects but does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your solution would be something like this:

```
def detect[K,V]( map : Map[K,V], value : K  ) : Boolean = { 
  map.keySet.contains( value )
}
```

You declare the generic parameters after the method name and then use them as the types at your parameters.